# without refreshing the page how to replace and display the updated values from database using ajax/jquery in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

Here when the likes() function is call through ajax the function gets executed properly without refreshing the page, but in view the likes of user remains the same. When the page is refreshed then the updated values of likes are shown. I want that the updates likes also should be shown without refreshing the page.

[before refresh, but likes() function executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGtaB.png)

[after refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQhnI.png)

**Controller:**

```
public function likes()
    {
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in_user'))
        {   
            $this->session->set_flashdata('like','Please login to like.');
            redirect('login');
        }

        $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
        $events_id = $this->input->post('events_id');

        // $permalink = $this->input->post('permalink');
        $data = array(
                'user_id' => $this->input->post('user_id'),
                'events_id' => $this->input->post('events_id'),
                'likes' => 1
        );

        $check_likes = $this->events_model->check_likes($user_id,$events_id);

        if(empty($check_likes))
        {
            $this->events_model->create_likes($data);
            // redirect('events/view/' .$permalink);
        }
        else
        {
            if($check_likes['likes'] == 1)
            {
                    $this->events_model->unlike($events_id,$user_id);
                    // redirect('events/view/' .$permalink);
            }
            else
            {
                    $this->events_model->update_like($events_id,$user_id);
                    // redirect('events/view/' .$permalink);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Model:**

```
public function create_likes($data){
        return $this->db->insert('flix_likes',$data);
    }
public function get_likes($events_id)
    {   
        $this->db->select('flix_profiles.name,flix_likes.*');
        $this->db->from('flix_profiles');
        $this->db->join('flix_likes','flix_likes.user_id = flix_profiles.user_id');
        $this->db->where('flix_likes.events_id',$events_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

**View:**

```
<form id="form">
                    <?php 
                    $cnt=0;
                    foreach ($likes as $value)
                    { 
                        $cnt += $value['likes'];
                    } ?>
                    <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('id'); ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id="events_id" name="events_id" value="<?php echo $events['events_id']; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id="permalink" name="permalink" value="<?php echo $events['permalink']; ?>">
                    <button class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x"></button> <b style="font-size:'20';"><?php if(!empty($likes)) { echo $cnt." Likes."; } ?></b>
                </form>
```

**Jquery/ajax:**

```
$(function () {
 $("#form").submit(function(e){
  var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
  var events_id = $('#events_id').val();
  var permalink = $('#permalink').val();

  $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'<?php echo base_url('events/likes'); ?>',
          data:{'user_id':user_id,'events_id':events_id,},
          success:function(data){
               console.log('success');
          }
      });
  return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: You could return current likes count in the likes function on your controller and have it parsed in your javascript to update part of the page that shows like button

Comment: how to parse in javascript? @Pratansyah

Comment: Where is echo result after successful completion of ajax?

Comment: I'm not displaying anything after ajax success... @AnandPandey

Comment: Why not displaying means you have to display count of likes. If you not display than why are you called ajax, you can submit instead.

Comment: I want to display updated likes after success, which is currently updated after page refresh as shown above in image, that I don't want, I want it without page reload @AnandPandey

Comment: I give the solution in answer.

Comment: OK thanks @AnandPandey I will try your solution.

Comment: Make sure you echo the count of likes in the likes() function.

Answer (score 0):

first stop form submit then reflect the values after ajax success.

```
$(function () {
 $("#form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //-------------------
  var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
  var events_id = $('#events_id').val();
  var permalink = $('#permalink').val();

  $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'<?php echo base_url('events/likes'); ?>',
          data:{'user_id':user_id,'events_id':events_id,},
          success:function(data){
              var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);  //--------
                $('#likes').text(jsonData.likes); 
               console.log('success');
          }
      });
  return false;
 });
});
```